# How to change the font, font size, and font color in JQ Grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

[image: I]

I want change all of fonts of the grid to Arial. Change the header font-weight bold and make the header color blue. Size of all fonts will be 12px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact changes could depend on version of jqGrid and the fork which you use. Ch make the changes which you asked you should use CSS like

```css
.ui-jqgrid {
    font-family: Arial;
}
.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-view {
    font-size: 12px;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hdiv .ui-jqgrid-labels .ui-th-column {
    color: blue;
}
```

If you use `filterToolbar` then you should need to add

```css
.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-view input,
.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-view select,
.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-view textarea,
.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-view button {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

additionally. After changing the font size you could want to change some `padding` values used in the grid.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/ChangeFont.htm) uses free jqGrid 4.9 and it set `red` color instead of `blue` to display the results more clear on jQuery UI Theme which I use.

Answer (score 1):

```
table{
 font-family:'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
}
th{
 color:blue;
 font-weight:bold;
}
```

You can change the style of a JQ grid like any other html element.

Comment: I have tried it in a style tag of my jqgrid page. But its not working. @MrSangrief

Comment: The JQ grid styling is inside a Media query (@medie=screen) you can try adding '!important;' at the end of your css rule.